# Add a section for video links in the SO careers profile page

Tags: feature-request, jobs

In the profile page of Stack Overflow Careers job seekers can add links to relevant books, articles and blog posts they've written in the "Writing" section. That's great, but I think that there's a missing section that would nicely complement that one: the "Videos" section.

Why? Well, some people give talks about topics they master in technical events, other record video tutorials at home... I think that most times this material is worth being included in a person's profile, and thus should have its own section.

I see that as a workaround, the site allows adding YouTube and Vimeo links in the "Articles & Blogs" section, but it looks a bit awkward.

Comment: +1 Good suggestion... The video section could also be useful for adding 'Hackathon' presentation or developer conference talk...